# Why can't I eject my iPod?

Tags: itunes, ipod

I keep getting an error saying:

**This is no disk in the drive. Please instead a disk into drive I:**

Then I get an error saying;

**The iPod cannot be ejected because it contains file that are in use by another application**

How is this possible, why would any other application be looking at my iTunes files?

any suggestions?

Comment: If you use Windows on your computer, is there a box popping up asking about how to handle the drive plugged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is Windows: Antivirus scaning your iPod? Several other fixes here: ["Ipod cannot be ejected" - Page 2 - iLounge Forums](http://forums.ilounge.com/showthread.php?t=63554&page=2).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. All I did was a reset of my iPod, and it really seemed to cure the issue. I hope that will work for you too!